# Using cypress, I'm trying to mimic a clicking behaviour into a 'View' selector, but it's not really a button, it's a key

Tags: testing, automation, cypress

So so far I have this:

```
 cy.get(decarbRoadmapPage.juneAsset).click()
        //div[contains(text(), "June Asset")]/following-sibling::div[2]
```

The second part is where I get confused, I need to put it in a method that will allow cypress to actually detect it

Comment: Hi , can u explain a bit more with example ?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the package, xpath is not supported, however, there is a [plugin](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-xpath) for that if you choose to continue using it.

Install the plugin into your local repo, then add the following line in your `cypress/support/index.js` file.

```js
require('cypress-xpath')
```

Then in your spec files you can use the custom command `cy.xpath()`.

```
// intelliSense
/// <reference types="cypress-xpath" />

//decarbRoadmapPage.juneAsset contains xpath below
//div[contains(text(), "June Asset")]/following-sibling::div[2]
cy.get(decarbRoadmapPage.juneAsset).click()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, so do I add this part: //decarbRoadmapPage.juneAsset contains xpath below
//div[contains(text(), "June Asset")]/following-sibling::div[2] in the before ?

Comment: Just worked it out i think: cy.xpath('//div[contains(text(), "June Asset")]/following-sibling::div[2]')